# How do I determine if a surface is closed?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

Say I had a parameterization of a surface and I wanted to determine if the surface was closed, to determine the applicability of divergence theorem.  My math professor said a surface is closed if it does not have a "boundary", such as the sphere or the torus. How would I determine this mathematically? Is there a specific property that is satisfied?

Comment: I'm confused.  The question says "parameterization", but the example gives explicit equations.  These strike me as two different problems.

Comment: They are, sorry.  If you answer either one, it helps.  The original one a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many situations, we can use the inverse function theorem: Suppose that $f:M\to N$ parameterizes a manifold $N$ using a manifold $M$ without boundary.  If $N$ has a boundary point $f(x)$, then $f$ cannot be a local isomorphism at $x$, so $Df_x$ must be a singular matrix.  If $f$ is a sufficiently nice parameterization, this is both necessary and sufficient.

In general, this is a difficult problem without restricting the meaning of parameterization, since boundary points may be produced locally but "covered up" globally.  For example, consider the map $[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x\mapsto x\sin x$, or the map $[0,\infty) \to S^1$ given by $x\mapsto e^{4\arctan x}$.  These are "parameterizations" of closed 1-manifolds by non-closed 1-manifolds.

For a surface: take $z\mapsto z^2$ as a map from the upper-half complex plane to $\mathbb{C}$.  These are "bad" parameterizations that nevertheless give closed manifolds because they cover up their problems at the boundary.